# Передать в jquery данные из <input> как две переменные -- динамические значения id= и value=

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Я использую clockpicker (https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) для создания формы ввода времени на php странице.

Страница работает так:

```
<?php while // ...извлекаются строки из таблицы mysql

// генерируется много (около 30, может быть как меньше, так и больше) вот таких карточек, каждая из которые имеет случайные значения card_numuber и card_time:

echo <div id='card'> ;
echo <div id='$row['card_numuber']'> $row['card_numuber']</div> ;
echo <div class='input-group clockpicker-with-callbacks'><input id='$row['card_numuber']' type='text' class='form-control' value=".$row['card_time']."></div>;
echo </div> ;
?>
```

Далее, с помощью вот такого скрипта:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        afterDone: function() {
        var card_time = ??? // не знаю, как указать именно ввод из определеного поля input clockpicker'ом
        var card_numuber = ??? // не знаю, как указать уникальный id из 30, полученных из базы данных значений

        console.log(card_numuber, card_time);
        $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
            card_numuber: card_numuber, card_time: card_time
        })

        }
    })
</script>
```

Я планирую получить переменные, чтобы передать их в базу данных mysql с помощью другого php скрипта (эту часть я уже сделал).

Т.е. мне нужно передать в jquery две переменные, данные соответствуют:

card_time это value=".$row['card_time']."
card_numuber это id='$row['card_numuber']'

Данные динамические, случайные и уникальные.

Вопрос: как мне это сделать? Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что как следует обходиться с clockpicker'ом:

```
    $('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').each(function() {
    var input = $(this).find("input")[0];
    $(this).clockpicker({
        donetext: 'Done',
        afterDone: function() {
            var card_time = input.value; // The current value of the input
            var card_numuber = input.id; // The input's ID

            console.log(card_numuber, card_time);
            $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
                card_numuber: card_numuber, card_time: card_time
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').clockpicker({
    donetext: 'Done',
    afterDone: function() {
    var card_time = $(this).val();
    var card_numuber = $(this).attr('id');

    console.log(card_numuber, card_time);
    $.post( "2_settime.php", { 
        card_numuber: card_numuber, card_time: card_time
    })

    }
})
```

Comment: У меня на странице ~30 карт и с вашим кодом передаются в консоль одинаковые параметры. Потому что id="card-no" и id='card-time' у всех 30 одинаковые. Жаль... выглядело многообещающим... Всё равно, спасибо!

Comment: id не должны быть одинаковыми. я привёл вам элементарный пример, остальное за вами. Редактируйте свой код.

Comment: id у меня могут быть только динамическими. Их-то я и не понимаю, как передать в js... Динамика и там и там (php и js)... Как это синхронизировать я не понимаю (

Comment: Попробуйте так (обновил в ответе)

Comment: Не получилось... В консоле ошибка `TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined`